# I am getting runtime error #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I am getting runtime error and android app is getting stop

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Here is My xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.Main_Tab"
>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="#00BCD4"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout1"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.Main_Tab">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#8BC34A"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">    </FrameLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is code activity_main_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_notifications" />
  </group>

  <item android:title="Other">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:title="@string/nav_about_us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
            android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: specify width for that line. for example 150dp

Comment: I would guess the issue is in your `@layout/app_bar`. Can you post that?

Comment: You have missed layout_width in a app_bar.xml. Check that out.

Comment: app_bar i have posted checkout  layout_width is there

Comment: Check my updated answer. You are also including `@menu/activity_main_drawer` and `@layout/nav_header_main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout seems to be fine. But you have included some more layouts within this layout.

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Most probably you are missing a `android:layout_width` attribute in the any one of these layouts `@layout/app_bar`, `@layout/nav_header_main`, `@menu/activity_main_drawer`.

Comment: i have posted @menu/activity_main_drawer checkout

Comment: nav_header_main has android:layout_width